# Unable to access tensorflow on jupyter notebook after the installation and activation

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, kernel-module

After going through the tensorflow installation process on the terminal and successful activation. I'm unable to access it on my Jupiter notebook through the change kernel tab.

Comment: You need to make sure that you installed tensorflow to the "same python" with the one your jupyter notebook uses. E.g. if you installed tensorflow to your vanilla python and your notebook is using anaconda you can't  access it. Could you provide more details so that we can help you out?

Comment: After installing tensor flow, upgrading it and even after running pip install ipykernel and restarting the jupyter notebook. I am unable to see the kernel. it is only showing "PYTHON 3'' when I clicked change kernel.